# console logging inside a thread is not accurate

Tags: multithreading, logging, log4j, logback

I'm using logback implementation and created an `AsyncAppender` so as to use logging inside a thread.

The thread will be something like a monitor: it consumes a `BlockingQueue` of Objects added from other threads and while the queue is not empty, and there is no blocking signal it logs the content of the queue. At the same time, the queue is filled by a few threads.

When the threads get the stopping signal from the coordinator, they interrupt, so they don't add more content in the queue.

The monitor queue interrupts once there is blocking signal (the producer threads already interrupted) and the `BlockingQueue` is empty.

There are two problems with the logging of the monitor thread:

1. After the producers have interrupted, the queue becomes empty so the monitor thread interrupts as well immediately, without showing all of the contents of the queue, even when it removed everything from the queue.
2. The order of the shown messages (both in console appender and file appender) is not the same as they have been inserted in the queue

I tried 3 different approaches: creating a static logger inside the thread, creating a non-static one and providing a loader from the class where the monitor thread is created.

In case I do everything in a while(true){} loop in the monitor thread, everything is shown but not in the right order, plus the fact that I have to find out how to interrupt the thread.

I checked also the case of the `MDC` but my problem is somehow different: I have to consume the product of the producers and do it while they are producing, plus after they finished in case there is still stuff in the queue.

I checked also the `LoggerContext` inside the thread and it's started is false. Shouldn't it be true;

Any idea on how can show all the content before interrupting the thread and show it in the right order, would be valuable.

Thanks.